# .each_with_object ruby explanation?

Tags: ruby, hash

Below, we are given an array called win_lose. We are supposed to create a hash that looks like the hash below. My original inclination was to do something using .count, but after trying for the answer, .each_with_object worked the best.

Can someone break it down for me on what the .each_with_object method is doing and the answer itself? I got the answer and figured it out from reading the docs but still need explanation on the method itself ...

Thank you!

```
win_lose = ["win", "lose", "win", "lose", "win", "win"]
```

Create a hash based on win_lose array that looks like this:

```
 win_loss_count = {
   "win" => 4,
   "loss" => 2
 }
```

This is what I originally tried without success:

```
win_loss_count = Hash[win_lose.map.with_index { |outcome, times| outcome = times.count }]
```

Answer:

```
win_loss_count = win_lose.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word,counts| counts[word] += 1 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`each_with_object` is very literally what it says.  It's like `each`, but with an extra object every time.

So for this:

```
win_lose.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word,counts| counts[word] += 1 }
```

You're calling `each`, with the object created via `Hash.new(0)` passed in as well, every time.  `word` is the word you'd get in a normal `each`, and `counts` is the "object" referred to be "with_object" (so, the hash).

Important to this shortcut is the `Hash.new(0)`. It means create a new empty hash with 0 as the value for all keys that did not previously exist, which lets you do a `counts[word] += 1` even if  it wasn't in there before.

At the end, `each_with_object` returns the "object", so `counts` is returned, having been modified for every word.

Comment: Thank you Nick for this thorough explanation. I understand it much better now!

Answer (score 2):

Nick has it exactly right and in fact there other methods that can pass objects into a block to help you with however your structure needs to output.  One of the most common you'll see in ruby is the `Enumerable#inject` method.  Your same answer can be rewritten like

```
win_lose.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash, val| hash[val] += 1; hash }
```

Which performs the same operation:

```
[14] pry(main)> win_lose
=> ["win", "lose", "win", "lose", "win", "win"]
[15] pry(main)> win_lose.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash, val| hash[val] += 1; hash }
=> {"win"=>4, "lose"=>2}
```

We're doing the exact same thing, we're sending in a hash who's values default to zero into the block and we are building our new hash with each iteration.

Comment: Thank you Anthony! Using .inject is super helpful. Thank you for bringing that to my attention and explaining!

Comment: Anthony - question - in this part: win_lose.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |type, num| type[num] += 1; type }  ... if I did not write the semicolon and type (or like hash like you have above), I get this error: "no implicit conversion of String into Integer". Why is that?

Comment: Sure, you have to return the hash back into the block, that's what the semicolon is doing.  At the same time, we instantiate the Hash.new(0) which fixes the string -> integer issue you're referencing.